# How to run start scripts from package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I've two scripts in `package.json`

```
"start:dev": "nodemon ./src/index.js",
"start": "npm run build && node ./build/index.js",
```

`npm start` works well.
I need to run `"start:dev": "nodemon ./src/index.js"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For most custom npm scripts you need to add `run` before script name
`npm run start:dev`

Answer (score 15):

**npm** - The main scripts such as start, stop, restart, install, version or test do not require run command. These scripts and some other are described in [npm documentation.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description)

```
npm start
```

The others need run command before the script name as was pointed by David.

```
npm run start:dev
```

**Yarn** - You can also use yarn and in that case you do not have to specify run.

```
yarn start

yarn start:dev
```

Comment: Great, but when we need to put a colon in between? like `start:dev`

Comment: You do not have to put a colon between words. It is just for readability. You can completely omit it or use dash or underscore instead if you want.